# How do I consume a SerializableEntity on my spring REST controller?

Tags: java, spring, serialization

So I have some standard client code that contains the following POST request:

```
...
httpPost.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-java-serialized-object");
SerializableEntity entity = new SerializableEntity(mySerialObject);
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
httpClient.execute(httpPost);
...
```

So the above code seems to be fine and doing what I want. However I am having trouble consuming my SerializableEntity on the server side. Here is what my controller looks like:

```
@PostMapping("/myEndpoint")
@ResponseBody
public <T extends Serializable & Comparable<T>> ResponseEntity<Integer> balancingPost(HttpResponse response) {
    try(InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent()) {
      MySerialObject<T> = (MySerialObject<T>) SerializationUtils.deserialize(inputStream);

       ... do business logic calls here...
      return new ResponseEntity<>(someResult, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch(Exception e) {
       ... exception handling and such....
    }
}
```

So I feel like an HttpResponse is the wrong type of param here for my controller but I am not sure what to use. Also maybe my @ResponseBody should be a @RequestBody in the param?

Comment: I think in your controller you have to set HttpRequest param before the response one

Comment: @m.benslimane as in something like this:    balancingPost(HttpRequest httpRequest, HttpResponse response)...?

Comment: yes exactly give a try please

Comment: @m.benslimane Hmm no luck still. Getting a null pointer exception

Comment: but wait you didn't change this line ? : 
InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent()

Comment: @m.benslimane No I did not change that line

Comment: so instead of  response.getEntity() use request.getEntity() like this :

balancingPost(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) {
try(InputStream inputStream = requesr.getEntity().getContent()) { .......